# Examples that are not Lebesgue integrable for any $p$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, lp-spaces

I've been trying to think up different examples of functions such that $EZ^p = \infty$ (with $Z>0$) for all $p$, but each time it becomes rather messy. Can anyone suggest some interesting but simple examples to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On $[0,1]$, try 
$$Z:=\sum_{j=1}^{+\infty}e^{e^j}\chi_{(2^{—j},2^{-(j+1)})}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\Omega = \mathbb{R}$ and $\mu((a,b)) = b-a$.
$$Z = 1 ,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \forall x \in \Omega$$
Then $\forall p \in \mathbb{R}$, $$\int_{\Omega} Z^p d \mu = \int_{\mathbb{R}} d\mu = \mu(\mathbb{R}) = \infty$$

Comment: On which probability space are you working?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Thanks for pointing out the mistake. For some reason, I thought the previous answer I had will be $\infty$ for $p < -1$, as well.